# Create dynamic button in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I try to add a function in a PyQt class, but it always returns me an error.

```
# Error: TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType' #
```

```py
def commander (self, arg):
    exec arg    

def aButton (self, layout, **kwargs):
    name = kwargs.pop("name","Button")
    command = kwargs.pop("command", "" )
    button = QtGui.QPushButton(name)
    button.clicked.connect(self.commander(command))
    layout.addWidget(button)
    return button
```

May be someone here can help me to solve that :')
Thx !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a function:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.commander(command))
```

Note the lambda will avoid the evaluation of the function call, so it'll call `self.commander(command)` only when clicked

Comment: can you explain with some details? I mean the solution works but I can't see why...

Comment: @SKYnine if you skip the `lambda`, that particular piece of code `self.commnader(command)` will be evaluated during that expression and never again. The result (whatever that is) will be passed to the `connect` method. Using `lambda`,  you will tell the interpreter that this is a piece of code to be executed later on (so it will be a function with only one statement). And you pass that function to the `connect` method.

Answer (score 2):

appears that in

```
button.clicked.connect(self.commander(command))
```

`self.commander(command)` is returning `None` instead of a signal or a callable.

Comment: Yes, but I just want to execute some code when the button is clicked. I don't understand what kind of value i need to return.
return compile(arg, '<input>', 'exec')
I try that but it's the same ...