# PyQt: How to connect QComboBox to function with Arguments

Tags: python, pyqt

QComboBox is connected to a function using following syntax:

```
myComboBox.activated.connect(self.myFunction )
```

But I need to be able to send the arguments from ComboBox to myFunction(). But if I use:

```
myComboBox.activated.connect(self.myFunction(myArg1, myArg2 )
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'
```

What syntax needs to be used to connect a QComboBox to a function that is able to receive arguments sent from Comobobox?

## EDITED LATER:

Here is the code resulting an TypeError:

`connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'`

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg        

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems([str(x) for x in range(3)])

        self.myObject=MyClass(id(self) )

        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.myFunction(self.myObject, 'someArg'))

    def myFunction(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
        print '\n\t myFunction(): ', type(arg1),type(arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create dynamic button in PyQt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730131/create-dynamic-button-in-pyqt)

Comment: Look take your code and change `self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.myFunction(self.myObject, 'someArg'))`  by `self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.myFunction)` it works perfect for me. As I said, you don't need to specify the arguments while connecting the slot.

Comment: @Raydel: I need to specify the arguments while connecting the slot. If I don't specify the arguments while connecting the slot how I would be able to send the arguments to the function? It is very straightforward if there would be no need in arguments to sent. But in this case the arguments need to be specified while connecting the slot.

Comment: @Sputnix I think you've misunderstood how signals and slots works. You CAN'T send arbitary `types` of arguments on a specific signal. The signal `activate` of `QComboBox` is emited with an `int` see: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#activated.

So you have to define you own signal, a signal that emit that value types you want (`MyClass` for self.myObject and `str` for `someArg`). And then you can **emit** your signal from the function that handles `activate` event. and of course you own signal needs a handler/slot  too.

Comment: @Sputnix The built-in signals know (this is predefined) how many and wich types of arguments are going to be sent to slots. The only you have to do is implement a slot prepared to receive such arguments. If the signal don't deals with the type of arguments you need, well, again, you need a custom signal.

Comment: Agreed with your point. But if custom Signal + Slot is not option then lambda is the answer in such situation (when there is a need to send arguments to function).

Comment: @Raydel It would be interesting to see how a custom Signal/Slot and their connection to arbitrary widget all could be achieved. Please post some simplified example. And ability to send the arguments down to function would be a bonus.

Comment: @alphanumeric: while trying to pass args to `myFunction` you called it so then `None` gets passed to `connect` instead of `myFunction` itself. The solution was to wrap the call with an ad hoc function and pass it instead: `lambda: self.myFunction(self.myObject, 'someArg')`. It's pretty standard way to solve this problem. You'd do it the same way in e.g. `tkinter`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After I posted a question Stachoverflow suggested a link which explained a lot. Here is the answer:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg        

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems([str(x) for x in range(3)])

        self.myObject=MyClass(id(self) )

        slotLambda = lambda: self.indexChanged_lambda(self.myObject)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(slotLambda)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def indexChanged_lambda(self, string):
        print 'lambda:', type(string), string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok, I discover why your code fails in your original question. No upvote for that? Is true the code you found works, but it not explain why your code fail in first place.

Comment: You should post the link then, because although we appreciate you taking time to post solution to your own question, it really does not say enough.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: sorry but you haven't actually done what you claim. The reason the code failed was that `connect` method expects a function object passed to it but OP actually passed `None` to it (while trying to pass args to his function he actually called it). The simple solution was to wrap `myFunction` called with its arguments in an ad hoc: `lambda: self.myFunction(self.myObject, 'someArg')` but instead you kinda derailed the question pointing to slots and signals mechanism when what @alphanumeric needed was a simple callback.

Answer (score 0):

#### Inference

> In here the *`activated.connect(yourFunc)`* after passing through decorator internally by library, yourFunc has two arguments without using partial from func tools that is self,val. Now when use pars from functools, decorator puts the self,passed arguments,val in yourFunc. Note the order of the arguments with partial and without partial

```py
    # Warning code must go inside extended QWidget class.
    QCombox.activated.connect(yourFunc)
    #! above line will pass two arguments to YourFunc function, so while accessing you can,
    def yourFunc(self,val):
        print(val)

    #________

    from funcTools import partial as pars
    comboList = ["Male","Female"]
    comboBox = QCombox.addItems(combolist)
    comboBox.activated.connect(pars(yourFuncWithCustomArguments,comboList))
    #! above line will pass two arguments to YourFuncWithCArgs function, socWithCustomArgume while accessing you can,
    def yourFuncWithCustomArguments(self,comboList:list[str],val):
        print(comboList[val])
```