# pyQT Combobox print output upon changed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

I want to create an event (print in this case) based on which combox and which row in the combox. I had a look on this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116763/pyqt-how-to-connect-qcombobox-to-function-with-arguments) and made some extension. Does it make some sense? When I press "second" in the left combox I want the output "0, 2" and when I press the "second" in the right combox I want the output "1, 2".

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.row = arg
        self.col = []

    def add_column(self, col):
        self.col.append(col)


class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        comboBox = [None, None]
        myObject = [None, None]
        slotLambda = [None, None]
        for j in range(2):
            comboBox[j] = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
            if j > 0:
                comboBox[j].move(100, 0)
            test = [['first', 1], ['second', 2]]
            myObject[j] = MyClass(j)
            for num, value in test:
                comboBox[j].addItem(num)
                myObject[j].add_column(value)
                slotLambda[j] = lambda: self.indexChanged_lambda(myObject[j])
            comboBox[j].currentIndexChanged.connect(slotLambda[j])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def indexChanged_lambda(self, string):
        print string.row, string.col

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to use lambda functions to send additional information if `QComboBox` is used, `QComboBox` can store information for each index, `addItem()` has an additional parameter where information can be saved and we can access it through the `itemData()` method, we can add another information with the `setItemData()` method.

To know that QComboBox emitted the signal we can use `sender()`, this method returns the object that emits the signal.

All of the above is implemented in the following example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        test = [['first', 1], ['second', 2]]

        for j in range(5):
            comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
            lay.addWidget(comboBox)
            for i, values in enumerate(test):
                text, data = values
                comboBox.addItem(text, (j, data))
            comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, ix):
        combo = self.sender()
        row, column = combo.itemData(ix)
        print(row, column)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! At first I got `TypeError: 'QVariant' object is not iterable` on  `row, column = combo.itemData(ix)`, but then I added `.toPyObject()` on the row and the problem was solved.